# enabling disabling asp.net validation controls using jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, validation

plz guide me how I can enable or disable asp.net validation controls using jQuery from client side. It is required to do so that valdiations can be done on button press.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty easy with javascript, just needs adapted to use JQuery:

- http://ajaxblog.com/archives/2009/01/09/aspnet-disable-enable-validator-using-javascript
- http://www.willasrari.com/blog/use-client-side-javascript-to-disable-aspnet-validators/000289.aspx

Comment: To adapt using jquery, when getting the element, getting by jquery returns an array so use the following:    ValidatorEnable($('#elementID')[0], true)